# Bash: capture the echo of a script in a variable

Tags: bash, echo

I have `script1` which calls `script2` which contains an echo statement. I want `script1` to send the echo returned by the `script2` to a named_pipe.
Is there a way to do it without having to change the code of script2? Like "capturing" the echo statements?

SCRIPT1:

```
...
case ${input_args[0]} in
        SCRIPT2)
            ./SCRIPT2.sh ${input_args[1]};;
...
```

SCRIPT2:

```
echo "OK: done!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redirect the output to the named pipe:

```
./SCRIPT2.sh ${input_args[1]} >"my_named_pipe"
```

Named pipes are just like files in this sense.

Comment: Thanks Tamas, I did like that but there where other issues in the code which prevented it to work. Now is working fine. The only problem is that if in SCRIPT2 you have multiple echo statement, they are not printed well :(... any tips?

Comment: So you want to send the output of SCRIPT2 both to the terminal and the named pipe? In that case you can use `tee` like this: `./SCRIPT2.sh ${input_args[1]} | tee "my_named_pipe"`

Comment: Thank you tamas! :)